# How to download sources from specific dependency in Gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependencies

I am trying to know how to get gradle to download the source of a given dependency. All that I've searched has not work. I've seen the property [DownloadSources](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html#org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule:downloadSources). But I do not know where to write it in my Android gradle file.

I've tried to write it in different locations, inside `dependencies {}`, `android { }`, `defaultConfig {}`. But no luck. In a regular gradle file like this, where have I to use `downloadsources`?:

### Project file

```
sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        //..
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ..
    }
}
```

### Module file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        // ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //....
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:latest.release'
}
```

Sorry if its a dummy question, but I can not find a solution.

Comment: Bear in mind that there is no requirement for sources for a depedency to be in an artifact repository.

Comment: But if `it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer` source is available, there is no way to download it source from gradle?

Comment: I have no idea, as I have not gone looking for that capability.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it for all dependencies. For idea use:

```
idea {
    module {
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

For Eclipse:

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
       downloadSources=true
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that is the problem, if of all my dependencies I want only the source for one, it's not possible?